# Derivation of a doubly robust estimator with clever covariate and inverse probability weighting

Tags: least-squares, causality, propensity-scores, weights, doubly-robust-estimator

With notation: outcome $Y$, (binary) treatment $A$, and covariates $L$. In Hernan and Robins (2020) causal inference textbook:

> To obtain a doubly robust estimate of the average causal effect, first
> estimate the IP (inverse probability) weight W = 1/f (A|L). Then fit an outcome regression model –a generalized linear model with a canonical link–for
> E[Y |A = a, L = l, R] that adds the covariate R, where R = W if A = 1
> and R = −W if A = 0. Finally, use the predicted values from the
> outcome model to obtain the standardized mean outcomes under A = 1 and
> A = 0. The difference of the standardized mean outcomes is now doubly
> robust.

The question is why we define the clever covariate as $R_i = \frac{A_i}{{\hat{} (_ )}} - \frac{1-A_i}{{1-\hat{} (_ )}}$, such that we can obtain the following doubly robust estimator for $[^1 - Y^0]$:

$$ \frac{1}{} ∑_{=1}^ \left[ \frac{_ _ - [A_i - \hat{} (_ )] _1 (_)}{\hat{} (_ )} - \frac{ (1-_) _ + [A_i - \hat{} (_ )] _0 (_)}{1 - \hat{} (_ )} \right],$$
where
$m_1(L) = \hat{E}(Y|A=1,L), m_0(L) = \hat{E}(Y|A=0,L), \pi(L) = E(A=1|L)$. This looks like solving two least-squares problems of $Y$ on $A$ and $L$, with and without the clever covariate.
Is there any reference on this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the response $Y$ also binary ? 
I have difficulties to understand the model which is fitted. Also, I didn't understand what $R$ is. 
Would you have the exact reference of this example in the Hernan and Robins book ?

Comment: $Y$ can be binary, but continuous $Y$ may be easier for derivation? Basically, you run a logistic regression of $A$ on $L$ to predict propensity score $\hat{\pi}(L)$ and then $R$. Then a regression of $Y$ on $A, R, L$. It's on page 167 of the book (Fine Point 13.2) and page 266 (section 21.3) https://cdn1.sph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1268/2021/03/ciwhatif_hernanrobins_30mar21.pdf

Comment: I think you mean "clever covariates" not "clevel covariates"?